# how to horizontal My image list in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I have fancy box image gallery in My page

```
    <p class="imglist">
      <a href="img/Ayubowan/7.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image">
          <img src="img/Ayubowan/7.jpg" />
      </a>

      <a href="img/Ayubowan/7.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image">
          <img src="img/Ayubowan/7.jpg" />
      </a>
<a href="img/Ayubowan/7.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image">
          <img src="img/Ayubowan/7.jpg" />
      </a>
```

and using this codes to create My pages.
https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/qVNXrZ?editors=1000

but now My images are vertical I need put it in horizontally. how can fix this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "My images" - you mean thumbnails on your page inside <p class="imglist"></p> ? Then you should show your page, because links and images are inline elements by default and therefore they would be displayed horizontally, like this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPjjNg

Comment: Use `flex` to the class `.imglist`  apply `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: " "` on flex-direction write col,row whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the height and width as

```
img {
    height: 160px;
    width: 240px;
}
```

Also you can try adding  `float:left;` property in css

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the **Flexbox** and do something like this:

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}

h2, h4 {text-align:center} /* optional, to make it look nicer */

#container {
  display: flex; /* displays children inline (side by side) */
  width: 1200px; /* adjust to your needs */
  max-width: 100%; /* for responsiveness */
  margin: 0 auto; /* horizontal centering on the page */
}

.imglist {
  display: flex; /* displays a's (img's) inline */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enables wrapping */
}

.imglist > a {
  flex: 1 1 calc(33.33% - 6px); /* each anchor tag (img) takes 33.33% of the parents (.imglist) width, that's why it wraps after every third anchor tag (img) / why -6px? because of the 2 x 3px margin (left & right) */
  margin: 3px; /* adjust to your needs */
  /* flex: grow(enabled (1)) shrink(enabled (1)) basis/width (calc(33.33% - 6px)); */
}

img { /* for responsiveness */
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

/* addition (recommended) */
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) { /* adjust the "breaking-point" to your needs */
  #container {
    flex-direction: column; /* stacks children (group1 & group2) vertically */
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>fancyBox v3.2 - Basics</h2>

<div id="container"> <!-- to wrap both groups -->
  <div id="group1"> <!-- to wrap the images and the heading -->
    <h4>Group #1; custom options</h4>
    <div class="imglist">
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/ndjyaOp0fOc/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ndjyaOp0fOc/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/A-fubu9QJxE/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/A-fubu9QJxE/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/rkkr6-2I4sg/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/rkkr6-2I4sg/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/mr_Tg4SI66A/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mr_Tg4SI66A/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/YEsedBccUEA/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/YEsedBccUEA/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Hw62tzAkXXE/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Hw62tzAkXXE/240x160"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="group2"> <!-- to wrap the images and the heading -->
    <h4>Group #2; default options</h4>
    <div class="imglist">
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Lzx4J_Pb3sk/1500x1000" data-fancybox="group2"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Lzx4J_Pb3sk/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/cZVthlrnlnQ/1500x1000" data-fancybox="group2"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/cZVthlrnlnQ/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/vddccTqwal8/1500x1000" data-fancybox="group2"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/vddccTqwal8/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Sj5efgWguDs/1500x1000" data-fancybox="group2"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Sj5efgWguDs/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Y7y7fe8hrh0/1500x1000" data-fancybox="group2"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Y7y7fe8hrh0/240x160"></a>
      <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/sYegwYtIqJg/1500x1000" data-fancybox="group2"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/sYegwYtIqJg/240x160"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made some modifications to your HTML structure to make it work as desired.